# How to convert an array into an array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

This is the array and I want this to be converted to:

```
// Input
["6-AA", "7-BB", "8-KK", "9-YY"]

// Output
[{"quizId": 6, "quizAns": AA}, {"quizId": 7, "quizAns": BB},{"quizId": 8, "quizAns": KK},{"quizId": 9, "quizAns": YY}]
```

Please help me solve this. I have tried to split the array elements and push the values as key value pairs inside the object, but was unable to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of asking us to do the work, show us your attempt and we will help you correct it.

Answer (score 5):

`.map()` it, split it up with `.split()` and destructure it. Return the destructured variables.

Explanation:

1. The `.map()` method called on the array is iterating over each element in the array, reassigning its value to whatever is returned in the function.
2. The `.split()` method splits a string by the delimiter specified and returns an array.
3. The variables `quizId` and `quizAns` are being assigned respectively the 0th and 1st element of the array the split method returned through what is known as destructuring (syntactic sugar).
4. The constructed object literal is being returned in place. Because the above variable names from the destructuring match the intended property names in the objects you wish to return, the following `quidId: quizId` is reduced to `quizId`.

```js
let arr = ["6-AA", "7-BB", "8-KK", "9-YY"];

let result = arr.map(el => {
   let [quizId, quizAns] = el.split("-");
   return { quizId, quizAns};
});

console.log(result);
```